# HTML History API on a local file origin null

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-history

So I am trying to make a one-page-web-app use the browser-back button.
There is a huge amount of HTTPRequests being fired loading pages and whatnot so the URL never changes.

According to documentation, I am suppose to use `history.pushState()` to simulate page traversal, and later use `popstate` handler to navigate. I am trying to test this out in a less robust environment, so I made a single HTML file with a few buttons that would simulate AJAX requests and content loading, it is all located on my desktop.

However once I try to `pushState()`  for these 'pseudo-requests' I get an error noting:

> Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/foo.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/historyTest.html'.
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/historyTest.html:34:29)

Does history API require the page to be on a server for it to work? I mean since origin is reported as null and not my local file path that would be my assumption.